# FileNotFoundError - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/background.jpg' - Django

Tags: python, django

I wrote the following code, in Python, Django framework:

```
class ImageGenerator:
    def __init__(self, tip):
        self.tip = tip

    def remove_transparency(self, im, bg_colour=(250, 250, 250)):
        if im.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA') or (im.mode == 'P' and 'transparency' in im.info):
            alpha = im.convert('RGBA').split()[-1]

            bg = Image.new("RGBA", im.size, bg_colour + (255,))
            bg.paste(im, mask=alpha)
            return bg

        else:
            return im

    def generate(self):
        print('Triggered')
        border = 3

        home_url = self.tip.fixture.home.image_url
        away_url = self.tip.fixture.away.image_url

        home_name = self.tip.fixture.home.name
        away_name = self.tip.fixture.away.name

        response = requests.get(home_url)
        home = self.remove_transparency(Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))
        home_w, home_h = home.size

        response = requests.get(away_url)
        away = self.remove_transparency(Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))
        away_w, away_h = away.size

        background_image = Image.open('/static/background.jpg', 'r')
```

When I execute this code I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError at /fixtures/view/54848

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/background.jpg'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/fixtures/view/54848
Django Version:     3.0.3
Exception Type:     FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/background.jpg'

Exception Location:     /home/sander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open, line 2809
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.6.9
Python Path:    

['/home/sander/git/football',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/sander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Server time:    Fri, 28 Feb 2020 18:56:54 +0000
```

I defiend the following variable in the django settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
```

I tried using the `static` function from `from django.templatetags.static import static`. This produces the same error. The `collectstatic` command also doesn't solve the issue.

Any one knows a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code breaks on line:

```
    background_image = Image.open('/static/background.jpg', 'r')
```

Since you are using slash at the start of the path, Python tries to lookup this file as absolute path in you file system. Make sure it exists as you write it there.

You can try using the full absoulte path, but the best practice is to use a relative path.

Comment: How to do it for css?

Comment: can you elaborate more @DerekPK? If you're looking for the CSS syntax to place background images inside a container (e.g. div) this should be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image